# Filling in text box with capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I have a text box that I'm trying to fill in with Capybara. I've tried to play around with it and try to figure something's out but my tests don't pass.

Here's

It's for this specific text box:

```
<span class="ui-grid-header-cell-label ng-binding" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="col.uid + '-header-text'" id="14213131-uiGrid-0008-header-text">DOB</span>

<input type="text" class="ui-grid-filter-input ui-grid-filter-input-0 ng-touched" ng-model="colFilter.term" ng-attr-placeholder="{{colFilter.placeholder || ''}}" aria-label="Filter for column" placeholder="" aria-invalid="false" style="">
```

Here's the code I have.

```
find('ui-grid-filter-input ui-grid-filter-input-0 ng-touched').set('1414234')
```

Ideally I'm trying to find this specific text box and type something in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill the *`<input>`* using Capybara you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
find('[aria-label=Filter for column]').set('1414234')
```

or

```
find('input[aria-label=Filter for column]').set('1414234')
```

Comment: It's giving me element not found.

Comment: Checkout the second option.

Comment: Failure/Error: find('ui-grid-filter-input ui-grid-filter-input-0 ng-touched').set('123231')
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "ui-grid-filter-input ui-grid-filter-input-0 ng-touched"

Comment: Tried both one and two

Comment: I just used Xpath for this.

Answer (score 0):

As a CSS selector 'ui-grid-filter-input ui-grid-filter-input-0 ng-touched' is looking for a `ng-touched` element which is a descendant of a `ui-grid-filter-input-0` element which is a descendant of a `ui-grid-filter-input` element - which obviously isn't what you want.  Since you're trying to match on classes you need to use the CSS class selector which starts with `.`

```
find('.ui-grid-filter-input.ui-grid-filter-input-0.ng-touched')
```

would be the correct way to do what you were doing, however you probably don't really need all those classes, and the more you specify the more brittle you are making your selectors. It's likely that just

```
find('.ui-grid-filter-input-0').set('1414234')
```

would do what you want - or better

```
find('.ui-grid-filter-input-0').fill_in(with: '1414234')
```